# mailto links not working

Tags: email, thunderbird

Using:
Ubuntu 22.04, Firefox snap, Thunderbird snap.

If a website has a simple `<a href="mailto:john@gmail.com">Click to email</a>` and I click on the link on Firefox, instead of opening a new composition window in the already running thunderbird, i get the attached error message.

Any ideas?  I am flexible to change the HTML if that will help, as mostly I am using my own PHP scripts for contacting my clients.

[image]

Comment: It's not the HTML. Do you have Firefox set to use Thunderbird for mailto links? It'll be somewhere in your settings

Comment: Thanks. Yes, the HTML is absoulutely fine as it works on other operating systems. Yes, its setup as default email client, but I think becuase it's installed as a snap its trying to open a new instance of Thunderbird the the existing one conflicts with the already open one.  Strange...

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why that happens, but I have a work around in my case.
In  the setting of FireFox mail, choose other application and have that point to thunderbird-bin. In my case under the /opt directory.

Works like a charm.